# Excluding files and directories from tar

Tags: directory, tar

Why does the command `tar -cvpzf backup_140128.tar.gz --exclude=/backup_140128.tar.gz --exclude=/temp_intel *` not exclude the `/temp_intel` directory?

Comment: Because the `*` is expanded by the shell before `tar` can see it. Try `tar -cvpzf backup_140128.tar.gz --exclude=/backup_140128.tar.gz --exclude=/temp_intel\*` (notice the backslash).

Comment: There's a space before the `*` so I don't think this is the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this from `/`, the `*` will list directories without the leading slash. Try it yourself; do `for dir in *; do echo $dir; done`.

This is exactly what `tar` will see, and clearly `temp_intel` doesn't match the `/temp_intel` expression given to --exclude. Actually, I rather suspect backup_140128.tar.gz, if present, is also not being excluded.

So three options (I haven't tried any of them, this is theoretical):

1. Force addition of the slash by using `/*` in your tar command line.
2. Use `--exclude=temp_intel` so it matches (assuming you don't have any other `temp_intel` directories you want excluded).
3. Play with the `--anchored` option to tar, the description wasn't very clear but I think it may remove the leading `/` before doing the comparison.